# How to use select on domain model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have entities that I map with automapper to domain models and return them from the service as Iqueryable. How can I use .Select or use automapper projectTo on them to map them to view models, because when I try I get thrown an error IAsyncEnumerable cannot be used for parameter of type IEnumerable on the navigation property inside the domain model?

```
class HomeDomainModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HumanDomainModel> Humans { get; set; }
}
```

```
class HumanDomainModel
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

```
class HomaEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HumanEntity> Humans { get; set; }
}
```

```
class HumanEntity 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

```
// IQueryable<HomeEntity>
var homeEntities = homeEntities.GetAll();

// IQueryable<HomeDomainModel>
var homeDomainModels = humanEntity.ProjectTo<HomeDomainModel>();

// Here it throws the exception
var homeViewModel = homeDomainModels.Select(hdm => new HomeViewModel()
    {
        Id = hdm.Id,
        HumansCount = hdm.Humans.Count()
    }).ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: What is `homeEntities.GetAll();`? Do you want to map `HomaEntity` to `HomeViewModel`?

Comment: I want to map the entity to the service model and return that to the controller when the controller will assemble what its need by mapping the result to view model with select.Get all returns IQueriable<HumanEntity>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map `ICollection<HumanEntity> Humans { get; set; }` to `HumansCount`, you could try code below:

1. `Profile`

   ```
   public class ModelProfile: Profile
   {
       public ModelProfile()
       {
           CreateMap<HomaEntity, HomeViewModel>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.HumansCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Humans.Count));           
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use Case

   ```
   var humanEntity = new List<HomaEntity> {
       new HomaEntity{ Id = "T1", Humans = new List<HumanEntity>(){
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "H1"},
       } },
       new HomaEntity{ Id = "TT1", Humans = new List<HumanEntity>(){
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "HH1"},
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "HH2"},
       } },
       new HomaEntity{ Id = "TT1", Humans = new List<HumanEntity>(){
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "HHH1"},
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "HHH2"},
           new HumanEntity{ Id = "HHH3"}
       } }
   };
   // Here it throws the exception
   var homeViewModels = _mapper.Map<List<HomeViewModel>>(humanEntity);
   ```

**Update**

For EF Core, it has a concept of mixed client/database evaluation in LINQ queries. For your code, `HumansCount = hdm.Humans.Count()` will run at client side and `ToArrayAsync()` will run as server side or async.

Here are two options for you:

- Change `.ToArrayAsync()` to `.ToArray()`
- For this limitation, it has been fixed in EF Core 3.0, if you need to use `.ToArrayAsync()`, you could try migrate your .net core 2.2 project to .net core 3.0 with using ef core 3.0 like version `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />`

Comment: I want to map view model to service model and then materialize all that in the controller by mapping the service model to view model. entity -> serviceModel -> viewModel

Comment: Edited: I want to map entity to service model and then materialize all that in the controller by mapping the service model to view model. entity -> serviceModel -> viewModel

Comment: @SevginIbrqm Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Fail to reproduce your issue with your current sharing code.